# MVC Attribute Routing not finding a link in .net Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Fairly new to .net Core and MVC and failing to get the below code working. My aim is that when a user inputs `localhost/about`, this should match on the Phone action by default. If `localhost/about/Address` or `localhost/about/Phone` were entered, then we have our action and this should match accordingly. At the moment, none seem to work.

```
namespace learndotNet.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]=Phone")]
    public class AboutController
    {
        public string Phone()
        {
            return "+449876543210";
        }

        public string Address()
        {
            return "UK";
        }
    }
}
```

I do know that attribute routes can be placed on top of the action too so on top of `Phone()` we could have `[Route("")]` but I'd like to know if I can do it at the top level :)

Comment: This will be available in .NET Core 2.2. See this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/557) for more info

Comment: thanks @SimplyGed. I've checked my csproj file and found this:   <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
Also notice I am up to date so for now there isn't much I can do. Thank you for checking.

Comment: No problem. You can always [download the 2.2 preview version](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.2), but the RTM release is [due soon](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md#upcoming-ship-dates) :-)

Comment: I'll probably crack on with the tutorials against 2.1 for now :)

@SimplyGed Would you like to make your reply an answer so that I can close this off by accepting your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be available in .NET Core 2.2. See this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/issues/557) for more info.

You can always [download the 2.2 preview version](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.2), but the RTM release is [due soon](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md#upcoming-ship-dates)